# Which way of invoking parameterized Tasks is better?

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I want to provide an asynchronous wrapper around I a network I/O function. Currently I see two ways with only a small difference.

1. First

   ```
   Public Shared Async Function GetMacAddressFromArpAsync(ipAddress As IPAddress) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
       Dim t As New Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)(Function() GetMacAddressFromArp(ipAddress))
       t.Start()
       Await t
       Return t.Result
   End Function
   ```
2. Second

   ```
   Public Shared Async Function GetMacAddressFromArpAsync(ipAddress As IPAddress) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
       Dim t As New Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)(Function(ip As IPAddress) GetMacAddressFromArp(ip), ipAddress)
       t.Start()
       Await t
       Return t.Result
   End Function
   ```

Should I prefer first way (correctly typed, using anonymous function) or the second one (boxed in an object, no helper function created by compiler)? Does it make a difference and if yes why? Or is there an all in all better way to provide an *Async function for my blocking call?

**Edit:** Additionaly GetMacAddressFromArp is overloaded. It either takes an IPAddress or a String (hostname). If there is a way which saves boilerplate code this would be even better.

**Edit for clarification:** I got a list of n IPAddresses. I need to call a function for each of those. This function makes a blocking (network) call to the windows API (`SendARP`) which takes ~0.1 to 2s each. I want to invoke them asynchronously and parallel so I do not want a *fake* asynchronous wraper but a wraper which in fact makes my call async.

Then I want to call my wrapper function (for each element) in a way which results in a list of the (aggregated) return values or even better in a way that an event is raised every time a call returns.

I would like to use the lowest .Net Framework version which enables me to do this. 4.0 would be okay but I can not use 4.5.

Comment: What's wrong with Task.Factory.StartNew, Task.Run? The type of method you call makes no difference.

Comment: Any solution using `StartNew` or `Run` is a fake asynchronous wrapper. The only way to get a truly asynchronous operation is to pass it to the OS as an asynchronous operation (e.g., overlapped), and it looks like `SendARP` does not support this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you not do this at all. [Stephen Toub has an excellent explanation why this is a bad idea.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Even if you ignore the guru's advice, there are a couple of other problems:

- You're using the `Task` constructor and `Task.Start`. This is inappropriate for an `await`-compatible task; you should use `Task.Run` instead. I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) that includes that guidance.
- You're `await`ing the task and then returning the `Result`. This is unnecessary because `await` will return the result itself.
- Once you remove all the ceremony, it's more efficient to just return the task rather than making an `Async` method just to return the result of an `Await`.

So, if you do want to provide a fake-asynchronous wrapper (which I do *not* recommend), then you can do this:

```
Public Shared Function GetMacAddressFromArpAsync(ipAddress As IPAddress) As Task(Of String)
    Return Task.Run(Function() GetMacAddressFromArp(ipAddress))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it definitely made my current code better. Unfortunately my problem requires a little bit different soultion as far as I understand (see my edit).

Comment: No it doesn't. It's not `await` that makes execution asynchronous, it's Task.Run that does this. `await` just waits for the asynchronous call to finish. If you want to query multiple addresses at the same time, just do this in a loop, put the Tasks in an array and call `await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` on it

Comment: `Task.Run` is a 4.5 method which means I can not use it. I've just [seen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) I can just replace it with `Task.Factory.StartNew` (I'm new to the TPL). I'll give it a try in the next minutes.

Comment: @user1200847: If you are doing `Async` on .NET 4.0, then you need `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` which includes `TaskEx.Run`.

Comment: It works for me now, thank you. I was using AsyncBridge which does not provide `Task.Run` or `TaskEx.Run`. I switched to `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` now.